# What kind of regression is appropriate for this sort of dataset (from recyclable battery cells)?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I have obtained the following dataset, roughly in this form:

- No. of charging/discharging cycles: 1 2 3 4 ..... (to 100)
- Capacity (at the end of each corresponding cycle): 1.0 0.998 0.992 0.991 ...... (to about between 0.7 and 0.85 for the 100th cycle)

What is a good way to regress if I have this kind of data for slightly different 250 cells or so?

Let the regression equation be

y = f(x)

where x is no. of cycles and y is the capacity.

I would like to model to predict capacity at the 100th cycle for any new cell with the capacities for the early cycles (about to 20th or 30th cycles).

Then is it appropriate to try a single-variable regression for y = f(x)?
In fact, the number of cycles seems to be just a label (in a sense) to index each ordered cycle. Then, does it work (or have any meaning) as an independent variable or feature in this case?

Otherwise, I also have the data for time passed, voltage, current, etc. during each cycle, which can be used to determine the corresponding capacity (or change in capacity). Should I use this to model the capacity, not just using no of cycles (ordered)?

It would be greatly appreciated if you give any kind of advice or introduce some reference (including dataset/code available publicly, preferably in R or Python).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to build a function that only maps the cycle to the capacity then what you'll need is an estimation for a linear equation, this is a too simple problem to use a machine learning model since the relation seems to be linear with 1 variable

If you want to include the other fields(time passed, voltage, current...), then you could consider using a linear machine learning model, check this [tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solving-linear-regression-in-python/).